# Hide line in default state in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

How to hide line in default state in Highcharts js-script?

I have ~7 series on my canvas, 3-4 of them are optional and I want to make them hidden when the page is load, but also show them in legend, to inform user, that he can enable them if wants

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Oh, I found it, hope the solution will save time for someone. Use `visible:false` in series defenition

```
series: [{
           name: 'MyHiddenLine',
           data: [1,2,3],
           visible: false
        },
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, this isn't documented here: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series

Comment: Thanks George, +1 to zod this is not documented in the Highcharts api that I could find

Comment: `visible` is documented at http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.visible

Comment: `visible` documentation has moved to the series subcategories, e.g., https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line